# Convert some part of a string to int/double in c++

Tags: c

I am trying to convert some digit of a string to int/double. But I'm getting error. I have to find the digits from string and have to sum them.

#### Input example

```
92dt6s2zer8t5f6b5ds1
```

#### Expected result

```
125 (=92+6+2+8+5+6+5+1)
```

I tried this way :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

string s="96h11k4959q615948s50922o38h1453ij38w73413d5577lzrqw3780b389750vf100zd29z73j5wh73l6965n85vm77cw10awrjr29265289222238n10013uk10062f9449acbhfgcm35j78q80";
double sum;
int d;
int main()
{
    for(int i=140;i<s.size();i++)
    {
       if(isdigit(s[i]))
       {
           cout<<s[i]<<endl;
           //d= atoi(s[i].c_str());
           //another try.
           /*istringstream buffer(s[i]);
           buffer >> d;
           cout<<"int "<<d<<endl;*/
       }
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `int i=140;` and not `int i = 0;`?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: u can't sum a string .. do u??

Comment: Desktop\Code\try2.cpp|22|error: request for member 'c_str' in 's.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[]<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((std::basic_string<char>::size_type)i))', which is of non-class type 'char'|    ....for d= atoi(s[i].c_str());

Comment: i tried from last..so that i can identify if it's working or not..if that work..whole thing will work... @sahu

Comment: What kind of output are you supposed to get? One single value? The string looks like you're supposed to get an array of values.

Comment: it will find all the digit th it will sum it like 9+1+1+4+9+5+9+....=?

Comment: @mishir.ali You should add that to the question, because the answer now assumes that you need to add the numbers 96 + 11 + 4959 etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like :

```
for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
{
   // Read the number
   if(isdigit(s[i]))
   {
       cout<<s[i]<<endl;
       d = d * 10 + s[i]-'0' ;
   }
   else //add it when a separator is found
   {
       sum += d;
       d = 0;
   }
}
```

edited thanks to [P0W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870232/p0w)

Comment: `s[i]` returns a char. `.c_str()` is neither needed nor avaiable.

Comment: getting this error    .... C:\Desktop\Code\try2.cpp|20|error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|

Comment: @mishir.ali what's line 20 ?

Comment: @mishir.ali by the way, if the answer helped, mark it a a selected answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You must check first, is the character a number. You can use the ascii table for this operation. numbers in the range of 48 to 57(ascii).

Answer (score 0):

Using your initial `std::istreamstream` way :

```
std::istringstream buffer( s );
char c ;
do{
    long d ; 
    while( buffer >> d  ) // Keep on extracting digits until failure
    {
        sum += d ;
    }
    buffer.clear( ) ; // clear flags
}while( buffer >> c ) ; // Keep extracting chars
```

<sup>**[*`See Here`*](http://rextester.com/MUT35882)**</sup>